# linux command make command not working returns error 127

Tags: makefile

Here i am running make command which through below error.

i am using mac os, i have jq, gojq installed

```
/bin/sh: @jq: command not found
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

% jq
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.6]

% /opt/homebrew/bin/gojq --version
gojq 0.12.12 (rev: 655bcab/go1.20.1)

```
~~~
@192 % make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
@192  % 
192  % 
@192  % brew install make
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################## 100.0%
Warning: make 4.4.1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.4.1, run:
  brew reinstall make
satyam@192 % make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
@192  %
```

Comment: You need to post more details -- specifically what the makefile looks like.   The error `@jq: command not found` makes it sound like you have a `@` that is not the first character of a recipe.   (`@` is often used in make to suppress the echoing of a recipe line, but if it's not the first character of the line, then make ignores it and passes that character to the shell)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trying run a make file and `jq` dependency is missing in your system. On Ubuntu like, try:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y jq
```

Otherwise visit https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/